# Announcing the clock change in English?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It is well-known that the age-old, widespread, and correct practice is to [announce](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/purpose-of-announcing-molad) the [molad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molad) on the Shabbat preceding Rosh Chodesh specifically in the holy language of Yiddish. In contrast to this, in many synagogues I've attended, on the Shabbat preceding a [clock change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), the date, time, import, and humorously supposed implications on Sunday morning minyan attendance of the clock change are routinely announced in the profane language of <s>***ish</s> [the vernacular](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/should-we-censor-the-term-goy-when-used-in-english-to-mean-gentile), e.g. English. The former comes 11 - 12 times per year, while the latter comes only twice, so the latter is clearly holier. In addition, as the clock changes involve contractions and expansions of time itself, similar to the [spatial distortions](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/mikdash5/120a-mikdash.htm) that radiated from the mishkan, they must be extremely holy.

What <s>possible excuse could there be</s> is the source for making this holy announcement in a profane language?

---

PS Your site keeps messing up my title. I want it to end with "?!?!" or at least "??" to express how much I don't get this, but it keeps erasing most of my punctuation!?!?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Depends on the synagogue.

Comment: FTR, your censored English is missing an asterisk, unless it is censoring Engish.

Answer (score 13):

It's well known that angels don't speak the Jewish vernacular; be it Aramaic, Yiddish or Ladino.

Since we wouldn't want the angels to miss Sunday morning davening - *for who else would bring our prayers (for more sleep) up to heaven without them* - we make an exception and announce the time change in English.

Angels understand English, as has been clearly documented by Rabbi Holy-Wood.

Answer (score 6):

The Maharal in [Nesiv HaAvoda ch. 13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14202&st=&pgnum=121) writes regarding Shnayim Mikra v'Echad Targum:

> לפיכך
>    שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום שהוא ביאור התורה
>    כי אין צריך שבעים לשון רק כל אחד לפי לשונו
>
> ויש לך לדעת עיקר
>    סוד הדבר כי שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום הוא כנגד
>    ג׳ עולמות, כי התורה היא מעולם העליון ולכך
>    יקרא שנים מקרא נגד עולם הזה ועולם האמצעי,
>    והשלישי **הוא תרגום שהוא כנגד עולם העליון**

The translation corresponds to the highest world.  It follows each person according to his own language.

Now, Daylight Savings Time corresponds to the highest world (הצלה, saving, is of course<sup>1</sup> from אצילות), and therefore it is only fitting that it be announced in the translation.

---

<sup>1</sup> Totally isn't

Answer (score 6):

Your question is premised on a fallacy.

*The former comes 11 - 12 times per year, while the latter comes only twice, so the latter is clearly holier.* - The opposite is true as we know tadir v'sheeino tadir, tadir kodesh

Answer (score 4):

This isn't about lashon hakodesh itself; it's about holding close to the original language.  Of course for anything arising from torah this language is Hebrew, so it is proper to announce the molad in that tongue.  (While some might confuse Hebrew and Yiddish, I am surprised that you did.  I therefore conclude that you have begun your Purim celebration early and that this was an accident.  I will try to simplify the rest of this answer to take your current state into account.)

Daylight Saving [sic] Time<sup>1</sup>, on the other hand, does not -- shockingly -- arise from torah.  Why we therefore do it at all is a separate question, beyond the scope of this answer.  But given that we do, we tie its announcement to the language of its enactment, which in the US is English, the language used in the [legislation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1918_Standard_Time_Act).

One could argue that the US legislation is derived from [German practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States#History_of_DST_in_the_United_States) and that we should therefore announce it in German, or perhaps even Yiddish.  However, we do not recognize the authority of foreign kings nor bow down to them in any way, so announcing in German would raise issues of *marit ayin*.

Of course, Jews living in other countries that have clock-alteration laws should use the language of their legal decrees, and if this is a practical matter for you be sure to consult your local timekeeper (which is, I guess, how you got into this mess in the first place, oops).

<sup>1</sup> We see here the power of marketing.  Surely nobody believes that any daylight is being *saved*; it is merely being *shifted*.  And that's important, because if you could actually *make* daylight, or save it away for later, you would be into the space of sorcery and you would be in trouble, because only HKBH creates light as we affirm every morning.  So even if they *are* actually saving daylight somehow, they should keep quiet about it to avoid dragging us into their evil magical ways.

Comment: I thought DST actually did make extra daylight. Isn't that why all the snow finally starts melting around now?

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought so too, but my father explained it to me: it's not that there's extra light to melt the snow, but that we need to celebrate the chagim in their proper times so Hashem arranges for the snow to be put away before Pesach.  The light has nothing to do with it, and my father's a physicist so he should know!  (But, you might ask, what about years when it snows during Pesach?  Rashi asks that question, but unfortunately I can't understand the answer.)

Comment: Let it not be said that I totally make things up: my father actually was a physicist at one time. :-)